# Finding Radius Of Circle From Circle's Equation

Tags: trigonometry, circles

For basic equations like:-

$$
x^2 + y^2 = 4
$$

we can find out that the radius of the circle is 2. But for an equation like:-

$$
x^2 + (y+1)^2 = 1
$$

What will be the radius of the circle?

Comment: The radius of the second circle will be $1$, by the same reasoning as for the first circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2+(y+1)^2=1$ is a circle whose center is $(0,-1)$ and radius $1$. In general, $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ is a circle whose center is $(a,b)$ and radius $|r|$.[image]

Comment: Which application is this btw?

Comment: @OmarTariq GeoGebra, a free software.

Answer (score 0):

The general equation for a circle in the plane centered at $(a,b)$ with radius $r$ is given by
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2$$

The effect of $(x-a)$ is a horizontal shift of $a$-units while the effect of $(y-b)$ is a vertical shift of $b$-units.